# Javascript: RegExp Turkish Character Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working about javascript search function. `RegExp` is `'\\b('+word+')\\b', 'ig'` for selecting and getting position setted word but it just selects English characters no select Turkish characters or anything.

> Working script: https://jsfiddle.net/kv4jftcz/2/
>
> Don't working script: https://jsfiddle.net/kv4jftcz/3/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need use RegExp with `u` tag but javascript won't support unicode regex :( so to solve this problem you should redefine `\b`. `\ba` means `[^\w]a` so for turkish characters;

`[^\wığüşöçĞÜŞÖÇİ]` is key to go.

```
[^\wığüşöçĞÜŞÖÇİ](türkçe)[^\wığüşöçĞÜŞÖÇİ]
```

can be used but this time it won't find any `türkçe` in down below.

```
türkçe dili destekliyorum
```

to solve that problem you can add `^` and `$`..

```
(?:^|[^\wığüşöçĞÜŞÖÇİ])(türkçe)(?:[^\wığüşöçĞÜŞÖÇİ]|$)
```

thats it..

> **Note:** this regex will match previous character and next character. so you need to put them again. `(^|[^\wığüşöçĞÜŞÖÇİ])(türkçe)([^\wığüşöçĞÜŞÖÇİ]|$)` 
>   and replace with `$1<span class="match">$2</span>$3`.
>
> **Note:** you can use look behind and look ahead too but unfortunately javascript doesn't support look behind

```js
 var word = 'İpsum';
 var rgx = new RegExp('(^|[^\wığüşöçĞÜŞÖÇİ])(' + word + ')([^\wığüşöçĞÜŞÖÇİ]|$)', 'ig');

 $('p, p *').contents().filter(function() {
   return this.nodeType === 3;
 }).each(function() {
   $(this).replaceWith($(this).text().replace(rgx, "$1<span class='match'>$2</span>$3"));
 });

 var positions = $('.match').map(function() {
   return this.getBoundingClientRect().top;
 }).get();
```

```css
div {
  font-size: 50px;
}
span.match {
  background: gold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <p>Lorem İpsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut voluptatum, provident saepe. Culpa animi sint, itaque iure error hic qui blanditiis perspiciatis adipisci, libero quia veritatis dignissimos quasi id cumque!</p>
</body>
```

> **Note:** You can't search the special characters with this (like `[hi] spe.cial characters`). You must use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6969486/2588699)

Answer (score 1):

Regular Expressions in Javascript do not support Unicode out of the box, which is required for the Turkish characters that you are using (although [ES6 may change this](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/es6-unicode-regex)).

Additionally, boundary rules (such as the `\b` tags that you are using within your expression) are generally not going to be supported for non-ASCII characters, so that could attribute to this issue as well. If you remove the boundary tags, the following example using [RegexPal](http://www.regexpal.com) appears to work as expected :

[image]

You could potentially use a plug-in like [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/plugins/#unicode) to add some support for handling Unicode characters as well.

A better alternative still might be the [UnicodeJS](https://github.com/wikimedia/unicodejs) library, which appears to add this missing functionality, might be worth trying.

Comment: Could you give me an example about XRegExp?

Comment: I'm personally not terribly familiar with it, although it seems that you can add packages of character sets and it would add support for matching those. However, if you notice my updated response, it's likely that the real issue is the use of the boundary tags `\b`, which do not support non-ASCII characters, which your Turkish characters would be.